# Separate Subnet for Each Vlan?

Tags: switch, vlan, subnet, trunk

**Thoughts and Query**

I was tring to understand Inter-vlan routing and realised, that each exsisting vlan in the switch is configured with a different subnet.

Is this is a good practice or is there any specific reasons,like what are the advantages of doing this(as each vlan is in itself a separate subnet...just an analogy)

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Vlans are layer two constructs.  Subnets are layer three constructs.
In all but a very few exceptions, you have one subnet per VLAN and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have Router on a stick situation when single router is doing the routing for all these vlans.

Here you are a link to get the idea:

http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/336-cisco-router-8021q-router-stick.html

Basically you can't have overlapping IP addressing on a single router (ignoring VRFs)